# Data is not getting posted to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to post some data into my mongoDB. Here is my main App.js

```
const express = require("express");
const getData = require("./Scraper/altscraper");
const routes = require("./routes/routes");
const mongoose = require("./db");
const Model = require("./models/match");
const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/status", (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (error) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  };
}); 

app.post("/data", async(req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("Trying to get data");
    const scrapedData = await getData();
    const savedMatches = await Match.insertMany(scrapedData);
    console.log("Saving data to db");
    console.log(savedMatches);
    
    return res.json(savedMatches);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({error: "An error occured while fetching data."});
  };
}); 

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

My model is as follows

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const matchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  league: String,
  country: String,
  home: String,
  away: String, 
  homeTeamScore: Number,
  awayTeamScore: Number,
  status: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
  time: Number,
});

const Model = mongoose.model("Match", matchSchema);

module.exports = Model;
```

And my database.js is this

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const getData = require("./Scraper/altscraper");

const mongoString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

mongoose.connect(mongoString, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
  .then(() => {
     console.log(`Connected to database`);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("Error connecting to database: ", error);
  })
module.exports = mongoose;
```

Here is a sample of the output that I get when I run index.js
***Server is running on 3000***

- [   {
  league: 'Premier League',
  country: 'England',
  home: 'Burnley',
  away: 'Aston Villa',
  homeTeamScore: 1,
  awayTeamScore: 3,
  status: 'FT',
  time: '2023.08.27 15:00:00'   },   {
  league: 'Premier League',
  country: 'England',
  home: 'Sheffield United',
  away: 'Manchester City',
  homeTeamScore: 1,
  awayTeamScore: 2,
  status: 'FT',
  time: '2023.08.27 15:00:00'   },
  ***Connected to database***

I noticed that my console.log statements inside of my app.post function are not being logged which I presume has something to do with the issue. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: in line ```const savedMatches = await Match.insertMany(scrapedData);``` you wrote Match. but you are importing Model ```const Model = require("./models/match");``` im not sure if this is the reason you have this issue or just the way you posted the question.

Comment: Where is your code that posts the data to your `/data` endpoint? You should be getting at a minimum your `console.log("Trying to get data")` if you sent a post request to that endpoint. Did you maybe mean for `app.post("/data"` to be `app.get("/data"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have written **Match instead of Model.**

```js
const Model = require("./models/match");

let api = async (req,res) => {
  const savedMatches = await Model.insertMany(_data);
}
```